# installing php5-geoip fails

Tags: php, geoip

When I try to install php5-geoip on my debian, I get an error :

```
root@pandora:~# LANG=C apt-get install php5-geoip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-geoip : Depends: phpapi-20100525
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@pandora:~#
```

When I try to install the dependency, here is the output :

```
root@pandora:~# LANG=C apt-get install phpapi-20100525
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package phpapi-20100525 is a virtual package provided by:
  php5-fpm 5.4.45-0+deb7u2 [Not candidate version]
  php5-cli 5.4.45-0+deb7u2 [Not candidate version]
  php5-cgi 5.4.45-0+deb7u2 [Not candidate version]
  libphp5-embed 5.4.45-0+deb7u2 [Not candidate version]
  libapache2-mod-php5filter 5.4.45-0+deb7u2 [Not candidate version]
  libapache2-mod-php5 5.4.45-0+deb7u2 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'phpapi-20100525' has no installation candidate
root@pandora:~#
```

apt-get update and apt-get upgrade both works with nothing to update or install.
I can install any other package.

Thanks if anyone accepts to help me :-)

Comment: Hint: run `LANG=C <command>` to make the output English.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do edit my first message with english output !

Comment: "php5-geoip : Depends: phpapi-20100525" Do you have that dependency? Does it need a certain version of PHP that you do not have?

Comment: I already tried to install this dependency. But it doesn't work. I will edit my first post to show you the output.

Comment: So I guess PHP 5.4.45 is a different version than you have installed now. In short, there is no package for php5-geoip that you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the errors you're getting, you don't have a package available that matches your current PHP package. You have two choices. First, you can use [the new PHP version](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php) (no compiled code necessary.) If you have composer already installed for your project, you can do this easily:

```
php composer.phar require geoip2/geoip2:~2.0
```

Or, second choice, install the original package from [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/geoip). Assuming you have already installed the appropriate PEAR package, and have development tools available (e.g. `make` and `gcc`) you can try these steps:

```
apt-get install libgeoip-dev
pecl install geoip
```

See [here](http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_164/) or [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-geoip-pecl-with-piwik-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) for more details.